# mysql query to fetch the quarter month from table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
Table name: activity
Field name: ProcessYM
```

I have mysql data like below.

```
ProcessYM
==========
201312
201311
201310
201309
201308
201307
201306
201305
201304
201303
201302
201301
201212
201211
201210
201209
201208
201207
201206
```

I want to fetch the result like below. I mean, the mysql query to fetch the every quarter of the year like 201312, 201309, 201306, 201303, 201212, 201209.. and so on.

```
Actual Output I expect
=======================
ProcessYM
201312
201309
201306
201303
201212
201209
201206
```

I have tried the below query, but it does not produce the expected result.

```
SELECT distinct `ActProcessYM` from `activity` where `ActProcessYM`%3=0 order by ActProcessYM desc

Output of above query
=====================
201312
201309
201306
201303
201210
201207
```

It is much appreciated for your smart reply.

Comment: What datatype is ProcessYM?

Comment: datatype is varchar(6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modulo of the month part only. Your query is implicitly casting your ProcessYM as an INT.

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProcessYM 
  FROM activity 
 WHERE RIGHT(ProcessYM,2)%3=0 
 ORDER BY ProcessYM DESC
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93523/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

you should retrieve the last two digits from field value and do the logic as you are doing.

```
SELECT distinct `ActProcessYM` from `activity` where substring(ActProcessYM,5,2)%3=0 order by ActProcessYM desc
```

Comment: it does not yield the correct result, it produces 201309,201308,
201307,
201306,
201305,
201304

Comment: Slight modification in the mysql query gives correct result, SELECT distinct `ActProcessYM` from `activity` where substring(ActProcessYM,5,2)%3=0 order by ActProcessYM desc

Comment: yes, it is working fine. In the above comment, it is mentioned. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not-so-quick-and-dirty way of handing this date processing. I believe you're looking for a MySQL formula like this:

```
 yyyymm = TRUNC_QUARTER(yyyymm)
```

That is, you are looking for a function that converts any yyyymm month notation into a notation that shows the month that ends the quarter in question.

Let's start with an expression that converts any particular DATETIME expression to the DATE of the beginning of the quarter.

```
DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(value),'-', 1 + 3*(QUARTER(value)-1),'-01'))
```

This takes a timestamp (e.g. '2011-04-20 11:15:01') and turns it into the date of the starting of the quarter. (e.g. '2011-04-01')

Having things in this date form is helpful because you can use them for date arithmetic. For example, you can get the last day of that quarter like this.

```
DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(value),'-', 1 + 3*(QUARTER(value)-1),'-01')) 
     + INTERVAL 1 QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Here's a writeup on all this:  http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

I've found it helpful to try to stick to the date datatype when processing time series data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate out the month value before doing the modulo 3 (% 3).  Doing a modulo 100 first will do it:

```
(ProcessYM % 100) % 3) = 0
```

or

```
mod(mod(ProcessYM,100),3) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 SELECT distinct `ProcessYM` from `activity` where SUBSTRING(`ProcessYM`,5,2)%3=0 order by ProcessYM desc
```